# How do I implement a dictionary database?

Tags: java, database, dictionary

I want to implement a dictionary database of Japanese for an app. I don't know how to do that and I have found nothing online.

The first step would be: grab a verb from the list of verbs (if there is even a list of just verbs), ask (is the last character A?). If it is A, then the conjugation is X. If the last character is B, the correct conjugation ends with Y and so on.

So the user will see a random verb, and will input the correct conjugation. Nothing too crazy, but I want to know how to implement a database, like JMdict for example http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/edict_doc.html

Comment: Building any sort of bridge between Kanji and English seems to me to be way more complex than what you described.  You might want to see if any third party libraries are available which already do this.

Comment: Your question, and the potential answer, are too broad. Try researching and/or implementing a database for your objective, and ask a more specific question. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”. Questions that are too broad, are considered "off-topic".